Alternating sum involving binomial coefficients
I want to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n\choose i}
\frac{\left(1 + \alpha i\right)^{n}
\left(-1\right)^{n - i}}{n!} = \alpha^{n}.
$$
This is a guess based on the computations for
$n = 0,1,2,3$.
Do you have any ideas on how the cancellation happened and how to prove it?

Seeking to evaluate
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}
(-1)^q (1+\alpha q)^n$$
we obtain
$$(-1)^n [z^n] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}
(-1)^q \exp((1+\alpha q)z)
\\ = (-1)^n [z^n] \exp(z) \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}
(-1)^q \exp(\alpha q z)
\\ = (-1)^n [z^n] \exp(z) (1-\exp(\alpha z))^n
\\ = [z^n] \exp(z) (\exp(\alpha z)-1)^n.$$
Observe that
$$(\exp(\alpha z)-1)^n = \alpha^n z^n + \cdots$$
so this becomes
$$[z^n] \exp(z) (\alpha^n z^n + \cdots)
= [z^0] \exp(z) \alpha^n = \alpha^n$$
as claimed.

$\displaystyle +1$. Pretty fine !!!.

@stackQandA $[z^n]f(z)$ refers to the coefficient of $z^n$ in the series expansion of $f(z)$. In this case, $$[z^n]e^{az}=[z^n]\left(1+az+\frac{a^2}2z^2+\frac{a^3}{3!}z^3+\dotsb\right)=\frac{a^n}{n!}.$$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
This answer is similar to the
$\large\underline{\mbox{Marko Riedel one}}$ but it has a slight twist at the end.
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
{\pars{1 + \alpha k}^{n}\,\pars{-1}^{n - k} \over n!}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\pars{-1}^{k}\braces{n!\bracks{z^{n}}\expo{\pars{1 + \alpha k}z}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-1}^{n}\bracks{z^{n}}\expo{z}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-\expo{\alpha z}}^{k}
= \pars{-1}^{n}\bracks{z^{n}}\expo{z}
\pars{1 -\expo{\alpha z}}^{n}
\\ = & \
\bracks{z^{n}}\expo{z}
\pars{\expo{\alpha z} - 1}^{n} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\expo{z}\ 
\overbrace{n!\sum_{j = n}^{\infty}\braces{j \atop n}{\pars{az}^{j} \over j!}}^{\ds{\pars{\expo{az} - 1}^{n}}}
\end{align}
In the last expression, I used the
Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind Generating Function. $\ds{\braces{\ldots \atop \dots}}$ is a Stirling Number of the Second Kind.
Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
{\pars{1 + \alpha k}^{n}\,\pars{-1}^{n - k} \over n!}} =
n!\sum_{j = n}^{\infty}\braces{j \atop n}
{a^{\,j} \over j!}\bracks{z^{n - j}}\expo{z}
\\[5mm] = & \
n!\sum_{j = n}^{\infty}\braces{j \atop n}
{a^{\,j} \over j!}\
{\bracks{n - j \geq 0} \over \pars{n - j}!}\ =\
n!\ \overbrace{\braces{n \atop n}}^{\ds{= 1}}\
{a^{n} \over n!}\ {1 \over 0!}
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{a^{n}}} \\ &
\end{align}
